# Computing the fundamental group of a subset of invertible matrices

Tags: general-topology

I was asked to compute the following fundamental group.

> Let $R(2\times2)$ be the space of real $(2\times2)$-matrices with the topology induced from any norm. Define X={A $\in$ $R(2\times2)$ $\mid$ trA$\gt0$ and detA$\gt$0} where trA denotes the trace of A and let $ I\in X$ be the indentity matrix. Compute $\pi_1(X,I)$.

My problem is that I do not have an intuition what the fundamental group of X based at $\ I$ might look like. I could find out that $\pi_1(GL^+(2,R)$ is isomorphic to the group of integers. Since X is a subset of $\ GL^+(2,R)$ it might be possible to show  that $\pi_1(GL^+(2,R)$ is isomorphic to some group involving the group of integers but as I am lacking intuition I am not to sure of it. I am not looking for a complete solution but a hint on how to get an idea what $\pi_1(X,I)$ is.

Comment: Is there a convenient deformation retraction of your space?

Comment: I would not advise making a wild guess like "the integers". Instead, write down the set $X$ in coordinates, stare at it, and figure out how to set up a fundamental group computation using the tools you've learned (i.e. deformation retraction, Van Kampen's theorem, etc.).

Comment: +1.  Staring at it is a surprisingly useful and effective technique.

Comment: First retract $X$ to its subspace where each matrix has trace 2, and retract further to the  subspace where each matrix has diagonal entries 1, then the last space looks like $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:xy<1\}$, which is a plane domain.